# Where can I find information about buses in Giza, Egypt?

Tags: public-transport, buses, egypt

According to [wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Cairo/Giza#By_metro), there should be bus routes close to the Giza Railway station of Cairo Metro Line 2. Quoting it:

> any number of minibuses and buses go to the site (known as 'al-haram'
>   in Arabic'); they include the green public 900 and 997 buses.

Any ideas? Where I can I find more info on the bus routes in Cario / Giza?

Comment: I lived in Egypt for few years.. AFAIK there is no fixed schedules, just wait at the station and buses will come! there are many buses to Giza. Last time was few years maybe things have changed now but I do not think so.

Comment: That's good to know! What about route maps? And I assume buses only operate between certain hours? If so then what might those hours be? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buses run infrequently and are privatized so it's extremely difficult to document. Taking the subway to Giza and connecting by mini-bus is much more difficult then catching the No 355/357 behind the Egyptian Museum. It's an "unofficial" stop, costs two Egyptian pounds, is air conditioned and will take you right to the base of the pyramids.

Things to remember, you have to "hail" buses in Egypt for the most part. Behind the museum a local will normally do it for you and you can just piggy back on their quick acting. Bus numbers are in Arabic, mini-bus or regular. My girlfriend always tells people when looking for that bus, Arabic is backwards "7" "0" "V". Good luck and have fun. Egyptians are friendly and will help you if you ask, just don't let them lead you anywhere...you'll see what I mean ;-) All harmless fun though!

Comment: 357 is ٣٥٧? I assume it's still most significant digit first? Thanks!

Comment: @neubert Yup! I just distinctly remember the words "backwards seven, zero, V," figured it might be helpful if you couldn't remember!